# Is there a difference between Collection and Library in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

A task assigned to us by our professor states that we need to do the following:

Submit an sql script file containing your SQL statements to the following questions

- CREATE A COLLECTION
- CREATE ALL THE TABLES FROM ASSIGNMENT 1 SOLUTION UPLOADED TO BLACKBOARD
- ADD THE PRIMARY KEYS AND FOREIGN KEYS TO THEM
- INSERT (MINIMUM OF 3 RECORDS) TO EACH TABLE
- UPDATE AND DELETE (MINIMUM OF 1 RECORD) FROM EACH TABLE

However, in non of the lectures has he used the term collection, I've always heard library and some other stuff. What is a collection?

I am using notepad++ and set the language to SQL, and I typed in

CREATE COLLECTION, however, create highlights in blue but collection does not have a colour assigned to it (nor does Library).

When I tried googling for an answer, I got this from IBM

"An SQL collection is the basic object in which tables, views, indexes, and packages are placed"

So a collection would just be a library wouldn't it?

so if that's the case, then in iSeries (AS/400) I would type on the command line

```
CREATE COLLECTION ASSIGN1
```

but in a script would that be the same thing?

Thanks for your time.

***EDIT*** 
My professor sent me this as an example, a .sql file that opens in a program from iSeries called "Run SQL Scripts", however, he didn't explain anything, just sent me this as an example.....so is it safe to assume Collection is the same as creating a Library?

```
CREATE COLLECTION FARA042;

CREATE TABLE FARA043.EMPLOYEE (
    EMP_NUM VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT FARA043.EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    EMP_FNAME VARCHAR(50),
    EMP_LNAME VARCHAR(50));

SELECT * FROM FARA043.SYSTABLES;
SELECT * FROM FARA043.SYSCOLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CHARTER';
```

Comment: Is it SQL Server? Do you mean http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx?

Comment: well the book we're using is Database Systems - Design, Implementation, and Management (9th Edition) and it only stated as Introduction to SQL and often refers to Microsoft Access for examples, nothing is else is really mentioned by the professor other than he had us install Mocha and connect to our college Zeus servers, and or told us to use the college pre-installed iSeries Navigator

Comment: @YuriyGalanter we haven't done anything with XML and its not in the outline, we've been learning DDL and DML and just basic operations in SQL

Comment: I think you better confirm with professor what he meant by the first task. As it is - its widely open for interpretation and you wouldn't want to guess wrong.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I'll try to get a hold of him, he rarely responds to his emails on time lol.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I updated the question, professor sent me an example with no explanation, safe to assume collection is the same as Library?

so fara042 is the name of his library? and the table is being made inside?

Comment: That looks like a IBM DB2 command. Can you verify that? in that case CREATE COLLECTION is synonymous to CREATE DATABASE

Comment: outstanding, you're absolutely right, it is a DB2 command, I overlooked that, thank you very much, things are falling into place now.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter in [DB2 for IBM i](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm) (f.k.a. iSeries) we do not have a `CREATE DATABASE` statement in SQL.  You may be looking at the Information Center for DB2 for LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows) or for z/OS.

Comment: An IBM i system or LPAR (VM) has one system storage pool of disk drives, and possibly other auxilliary storage pools [ASP].  Each storage pool gets it's own "database" name in the system's DRDA Directory (WRKRDBDIRE), but generally there is only one for the local system, and other entries for connecting to other systems.  In this context every schema belongs to a database.  However, more commonly, developers on this platform traditionally refer to any table as a database.

Comment: Just a note hear the difference is tables created in a collection (schema) will automatically journal and tables created in a library will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. On **IBM i** (formerly known as iSeries, System i) the terms `Library`, `COLLECTION`, and `SCHEMA` all refer to the same thing.  IBM now uses the term `SCHEMA` instead of the term `COLLECTION`, to conform to newer SQL standards, but they are synonymous.  However, the term `COLLECTION` has been deprecated, and therefore should no longer be used.

There are however some subtle differences between `CRTLIB` and `CREATE SCHEMA' (or CREATE COLLECTION).

The [CL command `CRTLIB`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fcrtlib.htm) allows you to specify the description of the [library](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frbam6%2Frbam6libraries.htm), just as any IBM i object has an object description.  You can also specify whether the library is to be treated as a `*PROD` or `*TEST` library when someone is debugging.  On IBM i, when a developer starts debugging, one of the settings is a safety feature indicating whether the session will be allowed to update files (tables) in a `*PROD` library or not.

The [SQL `CREATE SCHEMA` statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzxcschema.htm), on the other hand, not only creates a library, but sets it up with catalog views and automatic database journalling (logging).

Once you have created a schema in SQL, you can return to CL and use the [`CHGLIB` command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fchglib.htm) to set the library type and description, thus having the benefits of both methods.

One other difference, the SQL `CREATE SCHEMA` statement will allow you to create schemas with [names longer](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzsqlidts.htm) than the IBM i 10-character standard.  If you do this, I strongly suggest that you also give it a valid 10-character OS object name, by using the `FOR SYSTEM NAME` clause, otherwise the OS will then be forced to generate a 10-character library name.

Comment: excellent, very informative thank you. I didn't even know there was a specific DB2 for LUW i thought it would have all been the same. But yes, I am using the IBM i or iSeries as my college has it labeled lol.  Thanks Warren! 
Maybe that's why when my professor dropped the Collection term on us I had no idea what it was since he never mentioned it before, must be an old assignment he's reusing lol.
This will prepare me well for the upcoming test.

Comment: if you don't mind, I'd like to ask your help on one more thing.

I'm using the "Run SQL Scripts" feature from iSeries, and I have a bit of code created so I thought id run the script.

the collection's table was created, and I made a syntax error in a table, I think I fixed it, but when i run the script again it says 

"[SQL0601] ASSIGN2 in *N type *LIB already exists", so based off that my collection already exists...but if i want to run more tests throughout my script how do i bypass this issue?

Comment: See the [SQL Message Finder](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzas2%2Frzas2finder.htm).  If you script contains a CREATE SCHEMA statement, and that is where this error is occurring, then comment out the line(s) with '--'.  But I imagine it is on a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement, with a constraint.  Add `DROP TABLE mytable CASCADE` to delete the table and any dependencies before the CREATE table.

Comment: outstanding man thank you so much, the -- worked perfectly. As did the Drop Table xxx CASCADE, after the schema processed the table after was also having the same problem, so the drop table worked like a charm. You're awesome Warren! thanks so much.

Comment: You can tell your professor that a DBA is asking him to teach [CREATE SCHEMA](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzxcschema.htm) which is the industry standard term. According to that same IBM reference page, COLLECTION "is non-standard and should not be used."

Comment: People from other environments ask about schemas, but don't know what a library is, and certainly not a collection.